# MUI TextField not accepting pattern

Tags: reactjs, arrays, material-ui

I want to make Material UI TextField to only accept number values, in the MUI documentation the solution is as following:

```
<TextField inputProps={{ inputMode: 'numeric', pattern: '[0-9]*' }} />
```

However this is for the version 5 of MUI, and in my case I'm using the version 4, so I tried as following:

```
<TextField
      InputProps={{
        inputProps: {
          inputMode: "numeric",
          pattern: "[0-9]*"
        }
      }}
    />
```

But for some reason, this is not working, and I can still type values other than numbers in the input.

Using input="number" is not an option, as I don't want to keep the `0` when the input is empty, neither I want the stepper to be visible.

Full example is in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui4-forked-0j98er?file=/src/App.js:136-408

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use controlled input and clean value from non-numeric characters

```
export default function MyComponent() {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  function onChange(e) {
    setInputValue(e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, ""));
  }

  return (
    <TextField
      label="number input"
      variant="outlined"
      color="secondary"
      fullWidth
      value={inputValue}
      onChange={onChange}
      inputProps={{
        maxLength: 5
      }}

    />
  );
}
```

I was inspired by @Dmitriif's answer because it uses less code. But I [tweaked it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) a bit.
[live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui4-number-input-forked-4mxifc?file=/src/App.js:0-394)
However, the `min: 0` doesn't work

```
export default function IconButtons() {
  return (
    <TextField
      label="number input"
      variant="outlined"
      color="secondary"
      fullWidth
      inputProps={{
        type: "text",
        inputMode: "numeric",
        pattern: "d*",
        min: 0,
        maxLength: 5
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`TextField` in mui v4 [also has `inputProps`  property](https://v4.mui.com/api/text-field/)  which can help you to apply desired attributes to the `input` element. However, you will need to set another property `type="number"` to make the component work correctly in your case:

```
    <TextField
      label="number input"
      variant="outlined"
      color="secondary"
      fullWidth
      type="number"
      inputProps={{
        min: 0,
        maxLength: 5,
        inputMode: "numeric",
        pattern: "[0-9]*"
      }}
    />
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui4-number-input-qb5wj9?file=/src/App.js:132-388)

Comment: maxLength is not working for number inputs :/